# How to write convertible code, 32 bit/64 bit?

Tags: c++, optimization, 32bit-64bit

A c++ specific question. So i read a question about what makes a program 32 bit/64 bit, and the anwser it got was something like this (sorry i cant find the question, was somedays ago i looked at it and i cant find it again:( ): As long as you dont make any "pointer assumptions", you only need to recompile it. So my question is, what are pointer assumtions ? To my understanding there is 32 bit pointer and 64 bit pointers so i figure it is something to do with that . Please show the diffrence in code between them. Any other good habits to keep in mind while writing code, that helps it making it easy to convert between the to are also welcome :) tho please share examples with them

Ps. I know there is this post:
[How do you write code that is both 32 bit and 64 bit compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533/how-do-you-write-code-that-is-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-compatible)
but i tougth it was kind of to generall with no good examples, for new programmers like myself. Like what is a 32 bit storage unit ect. Kinda hopping to break it down a bit more (no pun intended ^^ ) ds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a well-formed program (that is, a program written according to syntax and semantic rules of C++ with no undefined behaviour), the C++ standard guarantees that your program will have one of a set of observable behaviours. The observable behaviours vary due to unspecified behaviour (including implementation-defined behaviour) within your program. If you avoid unspecified behaviour or resolve it, your program will be guaranteed to have a specific and certain output. If you write your program in this way, you will witness no differences between your program on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine.

A simple (forced) example of a program that will have different possible outputs is as follows:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(void*) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This program will *likely* have different output on 32- and 64-bit machines (but not necessarily). The result of `sizeof(void*)` is implementation-defined. However, it is certainly possible to have a program that contains implementation-defined behaviour but is resolved to be well-defined:

```
int main()
{
  int size = sizeof(void*);
  if (size != 4) {
    size = 4;
  }
  std::cout << size << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This program will always print out `4`, despite the fact it uses implementation-defined behaviour. This is a silly example because we could have just done `int size = 4;`, but there are cases when this does appear in writing platform-independent code.

So the rule for writing portable code is: **aim to avoid or resolve unspecified behaviour**.

Here are some tips for avoiding unspecified behaviour:

1. Do not assume anything about the size of the fundamental types beyond that which the C++ standard specifies. That is, a `char` is at least 8 bit, both `short` and `int` are at least 16 bits, and so on.
2. Don't try to do pointer magic (casting between pointer types or storing pointers in integral types).
3. Don't use a `unsigned char*` to read the value representation of a non-`char` object (for serialisation or related tasks).
4. Avoid `reinterpret_cast`.
5. Be careful when performing operations that may over or underflow. Think carefully when doing bit-shift operations.
6. Be careful when doing arithmetic on pointer types.
7. Don't use `void*`.

There are many more occurrences of unspecified or undefined behaviour in the standard. It's well worth looking them up. There are [some great articles](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0004/) online that cover some of the more common differences that you'll experience between 32- and 64-bit platforms.

Comment: awsome anwser :) just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 6):

In general it means that your program behavior should never depend on the `sizeof()` of any types (that are not made to be of some exact size), neither explicitly nor implicitly (this includes possible struct alignments as well).

Pointers are just a subset of them, and it probably also means that you should not try to rely on being able to convert between unrelated pointer types and/or integers, unless they are specifically made for this (e.g. `intptr_t`).

In the same way you need to take care of things written to disk, where you should also never rely on the size of e.g. built in types, being the same everywhere.

Whenever you have to (because of e.g. external data formats) use explicitly sized types like `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 3):

"Pointer assumptions" is when you write code that relies on pointers fitting in other data types, e.g. `int copy_of_pointer = ptr;` - if int is a 32-bit type, then this code will break on 64-bit machines, because only part of the pointer will be stored.

So long as pointers are only stored in pointer types, it should be no problem at all.

Typically, pointers are the size of the "machine word", so on a 32-bit architecture, 32 bits, and on a 64-bit architecture, all pointers are 64-bit. However, there are SOME architectures where this is not true. I have never worked on such machines myself [other than x86 with it's "far" and "near" pointers - but lets ignore that for now].

Most compilers will tell you when you convert pointers to integers that the pointer doesn't fit into, so if you enable warnings, MOST of the problems will become apparent - fix the warnings, and chances are pretty decent that your code will work straight away.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no difference between 32bit code and 64bit code, the goal of C/C++ and other programming languages are their portability, instead of the assembly language.

The only difference will be the distrib you'll compile your code on, all the work is automatically done by your compiler/linker, so just don't think about that.

But: if you are programming on a 64bit distrib, and you need to use an external library for example SDL, the external library will have to also be compiled in 64bit if you want your code to compile.

One thing to know is that your ELF file will be bigger on a 64bit distrib than on a 32bit one, it's just logic.

What's the point with pointer? when you increment/change a pointer, the compiler will increment your pointer from the size of the pointing type.

The contained type size is defined by your processor's register size/the distrib your working on.

But you just don't have to care about this, the compilation will do everything for you.

Sum: That's why you can't execute a 64bit ELF file on a 32bit distrib.

Comment: when you say disrib you meen ?

Comment: @FredrikBostonWestman: this answer assumes a modern Linux/BSD-based operating system. An "implementation" of such an OS is called distribution; they're designed as a stable complete package where everything is specifically compiled for the architecture it will run on. It's hard to get such benefits with closed-source technology, obviously...

Answer (score 1):

Typical pitfalls for 32bit/64bit porting are:

The implicit assumption by the programmer that sizeof(void*) == 4 * sizeof(char).
If you're making this assumption and e.g. allocate arrays that way ("I need 20 pointers so I allocate 80 bytes"), your code breaks on 64bit because it'll cause buffer overruns.

The "kitten-killer" , int x = (int)&something; (and the reverse, void* ptr = (void*)some_int). Again an assumption of sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*). This doesn't cause overflows but looses data - the higher 32bit of the pointer, namely.

Both of these issues are of a class called type aliasing (assuming identity / interchangability / equivalence on a binary representation level between two types), and such assumptions are common; like on UN*X, assuming time_t, size_t, off_t being int, or on Windows, HANDLE, void* and long being interchangeable, etc...

Assumptions about data structure / stack space usage (See 5. below as well). In C/C++ code, local variables are allocated on the stack, and the space used there is different between 32bit and 64bit mode due to the point below, and due to the different rules for passing arguments (32bit x86 usually on the stack, 64bit x86 in part in registers). Code that just about gets away with the default stacksize on 32bit might cause stack overflow crashes on 64bit.
This is relatively easy to spot as a cause of the crash but depending on the configurability of the application possibly hard to fix.

Timing differences between 32bit and 64bit code (due to different code sizes / cache footprints, or different memory access characteristics / patterns, or different calling conventions ) might break "calibrations". Say, for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) sleep(0); is likely going to have different timings for 32bit and 64bit ...

Finally, the ABI (Application Binary Interface). There's usually bigger differences between 64bit and 32bit environments than the size of pointers...
Currently, two main "branches" of 64bit environments exist, IL32P64 (what Win64 uses - int and long are int32_t, only uintptr_t/void* is uint64_t, talking in terms of the sized integers from ) and LP64 (what UN*X uses - int is int32_t, long is int64_t and uintptr_t/void* is uint64_t), but there's the "subdivisions" of different alignment rules as well - some environments assume long, float or double align at their respective sizes, while others assume they align at multiples of four bytes. In 32bit Linux, they align all at four bytes, while in 64bit Linux, float aligns at four, long and double at eight-byte multiples.
The consequence of these rules is that in many cases, bith sizeof(struct { ...}) and the offset of structure/class members are different between 32bit and 64bit environments even if the data type declaration is completely identical.
Beyond impacting array/vector allocations, these issues also affect data in/output e.g. through files - if a 32bit app writes e.g. struct { char a; int b; char c, long d; double e } to a file that the same app recompiled for 64bit reads in, the result will not be quite what's hoped for.
The examples just given are only about language primitives (char, int, long etc.) but of course affect all sorts of platform-dependent / runtime library data types, whether size_t, off_t, time_t, HANDLE, essentially any nontrivial struct/union/class ... - so the space for error here is large,

And then there's the lower-level differences, which come into play e.g. for hand-optimized assembly (SSE/SSE2/...); 32bit and 64bit have different (numbers of) registers, different argument passing rules; all of this affects strongly how such optimizations perform and it's very likely that e.g. SSE2 code which gives best performance in 32bit mode will need to be rewritten / needs to be enhanced to give best performance 64bit mode.

There's also code design constraints which are very different for 32bit and 64bit, particularly around memory allocation / management; an application that's been carefully coded to "maximize the hell out of the mem it can get in 32bit" will have complex logic on how / when to allocate/free memory, memory-mapped file usage, internal caching, etc - much of which will be detrimental in 64bit where you could "simply" take advantage of the huge available address space. Such an app might recompile for 64bit just fine, but perform worse there than some "ancient simple deprecated version" which didn't have all the maximize-32bit peephole optimizations.

So, ultimately, it's also about enhancements / gains, and that's where more work, partly in programming, partly in design/requirements comes in. Even if your app cleanly recompiles both on 32bit and 64bit environments and is verified on both, is it actually benefitting from 64bit ? Are there changes that can/should be done to the code logic to make it do more / run faster in 64bit ? Can you do those changes without breaking 32bit backward compatibility ? Without negative impacts on the 32bit target ? Where will the enhancements be, and how much can you gain ?
For a large commercial project, answers to these questions are often important markers on the roadmap because your starting point is some existing "money maker"...